# 403 Error while moving code from Java Application to Android using JSoup

Tags: android, parsing, get, jsoup

I want to extract data from the table on this [link](http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?date=29DEC2011) using JSoup. When I try to run the following code in a Java Application Project in Eclipse I am successfully able to do so. However,when I use that same code in my Android Project it gives me 403 error loading URL.

This is my code:

```
try{
    Connection c=Jsoup.connect("http://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?date=29DEC2011");
    //System.out.println("got connection "+c.toString());
    Document doc=c.get();
    //System.out.println("reached");
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the Stack Trace it shows an error on `Document doc=c.get();` line so that means there is something wrong with the `get()` method.

What should I do to rectify this and successfully parse the page?

Comment: [Documentation on HTTP 403 Forbidden](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.4). This problem is at least not related to Java in any way. It's the server who refused the request. We can do several guesses, but best is to contact the server admin and ask them for explanation (after you have read the website's policy).

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply. But however, my question remains that why is that it able to get the document from the server when using running in the Java Application Project?

Comment: Start with looking at the request headers. Apparently the server is blocking certain UA's. But the server is not doing that without reason... I'd really contact them before getting into serious legal trouble while attempting to workaround this.

Comment: your android application is accessing the `INTERNET`, so you need to have the `INTERNET` permission set up on the `Manifest` file. Do you have it?

Comment: yep i have set the uses-permission as well in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

> response.ignoreHttpErrors(false);

to disable gets Server Errors (for example: 403. 404, etc.). If you disable, you can get code HTML from page.